# Highlight Cells with numerical value

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to highlight cell with number. This macro highlights cell with text also.

```
Sub high()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim yourrange As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each yourrange In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        yourrange.Interior.Color = 65535
    Next yourrange
End Sub
```

Comment: HI. HOw do i set a range for this to work. I only want from cell B7:D1000

Answer (score 6):

**There are two options for you: with VBA and without WBA:**

1) Using VBA

*without using loop, thanks to @Siddharth Rout:)*

```
Sub high()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Interior.Color = 65535
End Sub
```

*Using loop:*

```
Sub high()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim yourrange As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each yourrange In rng
            If IsNumeric(yourrange) Then yourrange.Interior.Color = 65535
        Next yourrange
    End If
End Sub
```

2) Without VBA, (thanks to @pnuts):

Go to "**Find & Select**" menu Item on the Ribbon and select "**GoTo Special..**":

[image]

choose "**Constants**" and select *only* "**Numbers**" and press "OK".

[image]

Now, excel highlighted all number cells:

[image]

Next step is to fill them with desired color:

[image]

Done:)

Comment: I would recommend splitting `ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` from the For loop and setting a range object and then sandwiching that between OERN :)

Comment: Kool. One small thing... you need to sandwich your `For` loop in `If Not rng Is Nothing Then` and change `MsgBox "There is no constants on the sheet"` to `msgbox Err.Description` else it will show the same message for other errors :)

Comment: I'm using `On Error GoTo errHandler` but you are right, it would be better:) Updating answer..

Comment: + 1 BTW do you know that instead of isnumeric() you can also use `Set rng = ws.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Ha! Your code is great!:) Why I don't thought about that earlier?)

Comment: @pnuts has a point. You can always add two solutions to your post to make it complete. You have already suggested a VBA method. Also worth mentioning the Non VBA Method. It will not only help the current asker but also any future visitors :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, ok:) I should switch my excel to english language to make screenshots:)

Comment: No need for screenshots a simple sentence saying "If you wish to opt in for a non VBA method, then you can use "Go To"  which can be invoked using `CTRL G` or `F5` from the worksheet. Click on the `Special` Button and select `constants` and then `numbers` under `formulas`. That's it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, updated:) thank you all for great work)

Comment: Wish I could upvote your post again :) But all thanks to @pnuts ;)

Comment: thanks Everyone. How do i Set a range. and still look at all constants. Do i change WS.Cell to B7:1000.cell

Comment: change `ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to `ws.Range("B7:D1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`